# Swift runtime error when adding elements to list?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm learning Swift through the Apple tutorials and Xcode is throwing me a runtime error when I try to add my meals into the ***meals*** array. I tried using 'append', but doing so will give me a "extra argument call" error.

```
class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {
// MARK: Properties
var meals = [Meal]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadSampleMeals()
}
func loadSampleMeals() {

    let photo1 = UIImage(named:"Chocolate")!
    let chocolate = Meal(name: "Great Chocolate", photo: photo1, rating: 4)

    let photo2 = UIImage(named: "Curry")!
    let curry = Meal(name: "Smelly Curry", photo: photo2, rating: 1)

    let photo3 = UIImage(named: "Menudo")!
    let menudo = Meal(name: "Red and ready to go", photo: photo3, rating: 5)

    meals += [chocolate,curry,menudo]
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime error? If it's "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional", it probably means your `UIImage` nil. It looks like the way you are appending to the `meals` array should work.

Comment: The runtime error comes out to be that 'the binary += cannot be applied to operands of type [Meal] and [Meal?]'

Comment: I'm surprised that's a runtime error and not a compile error. Does Meal have a failable initializer? In other words, init?() or init!(). If so, you need to unwrap your meals before putting them in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ConfusedByCode points out, your images are probably `nil` and you're trying to implicitly unwrap them (with `!`).

You have three ways to solve this:

**Solution 1**

Make sure those images exist in your project.

**Solution 2**

Make sure your images aren't `nil` before adding a new `Meal`.

```
func loadSampleMeals() {
    if let photo1 = UIImage(named:"Chocolate") {
        meals.append(Meal(name: "Great Chocolate", photo: photo1, rating: 4))
    }

    if let photo2 = UIImage(named: "Curry") {
        meals.append(Meal(name: "Smelly Curry", photo: photo2, rating: 1))
    }

    if let photo3 = UIImage(named: "Menudo") {
        meals.append(Meal(name: "Red and ready to go", photo: photo3, rating: 5))
    }
}
```

**Solution 3**

Make `photo` an optional property in your `Meal` class.

```
class Meal {
    init(name: String, photo: UIImage?, rating: Int) {
    }
}
```

Which would then allow you to keep your code (but remove the `!`).

```
func loadSampleMeals() {
    let photo1 = UIImage(named:"Chocolate")
    let chocolate = Meal(name: "Great Chocolate", photo: photo1, rating: 4)

    let photo2 = UIImage(named: "Curry")
    let curry = Meal(name: "Smelly Curry", photo: photo2, rating: 1)

    let photo3 = UIImage(named: "Menudo")
    let menudo = Meal(name: "Red and ready to go", photo: photo3, rating: 5)

    meals += [chocolate,curry,menudo]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try meals.append() instead of the operator